# Django upload of image fails after the first upload after server is booted up

Tags: django, file-upload

I have a Django project which accepts image uploads via the REST Framework. The first time I upload an image from my app it works fine but all subsequent attempts to upload images fail. If I reboot the server it works for the first image upload and then fails for all subsequent uploads. Every time I reboot the server it works for just one upload. The error I am getting is:

```
ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

The full log looks like this:

```
    [16/Oct/2016 17:18:03] "POST /api/photoupload/ HTTP/1.1" 201 399
Internal Server Error: /api/photoupload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 149, in get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 147, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 58, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 87, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 466, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 463, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
self.perform_create(serializer)
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/items/views.py", line 379, in perform_create
the_photo_url = the_photo.photo.url
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 68, in _get_url
self._require_file()
File "/Users/billnoble/Documents/YHistory-Server/yhistoryvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/files.py", line 46, in _require_file
raise ValueError("The '%s' attribute has no file associated with it." % self.field.name)
ValueError: The 'photo' attribute has no file associated with it.
[16/Oct/2016 17:20:08] "POST /api/photoupload/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17754
```

My view code looks like this:

```js
class PhotoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Photo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PhotoSerializer
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        #the_itemID = self.request.data['item_id']
       
        the_username = self.request.user
      
        the_title = self.request.data['title']
        the_item_type = self.request.data['item_type']
        the_longitude = self.request.data['longitude']
        the_latitude = self.request.data['latitude']
        the_timestamp = self.request.data['timestamp']           
        the_parsed_timestamp = datetime.strptime(the_timestamp, "%Y:%m:%d %H:%M:%S")

        the_user = User.objects.get(username=the_username)
        the_item = Item.objects.get(pk=2)           

        # Create the photo record with the uploaded photo
        the_photo = serializer.save(user=the_user,
                                    item=the_item,
                                    photo=self.request.data.get('photo'),
                                    photo_thumbnail=self.request.data.get('photo'))
        the_photo_url = the_photo.photo.url
        
        # Now create the Item record using the other parameters and the info from the photo record
        the_item = Item.objects.create(url=the_photo_url,
                                       owner=the_user,
                                       item_type=the_item_type,
                                       title=the_title,
                                       active = 1,
                                       lat = the_latitude,
                                       long = the_longitude,
                                       date_taken = the_parsed_timestamp)
        
        the_item.save()

        # Put the real item id in the Photo table
        the_photo.item = the_item
        the_photo.save()
```

And my model looks like this:

```js
class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="userphotos/",
                              height_field=None,
                              width_field=None,
                              max_length=100,
                              default='/none/')

    photo_thumbnail = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='userthumbs/',
                                processors=[ResizeToFill(400, 400)],
                                format='JPEG',
                                options={'quality': 60}, default='/none/')


    date_submitted = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Does normal Admin uploads work properly?

Comment: Good question how would I check admin uploads? Never tried that.

Comment: You need to add your photo model to the django admin with the use of the admin.py file

Comment: Ok so I tried doing it via admin upload. This succeeds in allowing multiple uploads but doesn't via the admin upload run the imagekit code to create the thumbnail. Not sure what this tells me.